# Gradle translate groovy to kotlin for plugins

Tags: kotlin, gradle, plugins

I currently have an init.gradle file which works fine:

```
initscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:+")
    }
}
allprojects {

    apply plugin: com.github.benmanes.gradle.versions.VersionsPlugin
}
```

Now I would like to move towards the kotlin DSL, as all other projects I am working on are moved over.

So I created this:

```
initscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath("com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:+")
  }
}
allprojects {
  apply(plugin = com.github.benmanes.gradle.versions.VersionsPlugin)
}
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
Script compilation error:

  Line 11:   apply(plugin = com.github.benmanes.gradle.versions.VersionsPlugin)
                                                                ^ Classifier 'VersionsPlugin' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here
```

when I try to put `"` around the plugin, I get the error:

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin with id 'com.github.benmanes.gradle.versions.VersionsPlugin' not found.
```

When I try

```
apply<VersionsPlugin>()
```

I get:

```
  Line 10: apply<VersionsPlugin>()
                 ^ Unresolved reference: VersionsPlugin
```

When I try:

```
apply(plugin = "com.github.ben-manes.versions")
```

I get:

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin with id 'com.github.ben-manes.versions' not found.
```

In the [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:init_script_plugins) I just found a hint about how to initialize a new plugin, not how to add an existing plugin.

Anybody here who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special Kotlin extension function for this

```
apply<VersionsPlugin>()

// or
apply(plugin = "com.github.ben-manes.versions")
```

UPDATE:
The first option works well for me. The full content of the `init.gradle.kts` file:

```
import com.github.benmanes.gradle.versions.VersionsPlugin

initscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:+")
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply<VersionsPlugin>()
}
```

Usage: `./gradlew dependencyUpdates -I init.gradle.kts`

The second option fails indeed, sorry. The reason is not clear to me.

Comment: Unfortunately for the first suggestion I get this:

  `Line 11: apply<VersionsPlugin>()
                 ^ Unresolved reference: VersionsPlugin`

And for your second suggestion I get this:

`* What went wrong:
Plugin with id 'com.github.ben-manes.versions' not found.`

Comment: Have you tried to add `import com.github.benmanes.gradle.versions.VersionsPlugin`?

Comment: many thanks. I tried the `apply<VersionsPlugin>()` outside of the `allProjects` scope, as I am used to that in the 'normal' build script. but having it inside there it works, thank you so much :)